# Moving the 3D cursor while in Blender 2.8's Grease Pencil Draw Mode

Tags: grease-pencil, 3d-cursor

Does anyone know if it's possible to move the 3D cursor when you're in the Draw Mode of Blender 2.8?

I'd like to be able to draw and move the 3D cursor to change where the drawing is done in depth, using the 3D cursor to determine that.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this possibility is currently missing.

You can work around it by setting a key binding for your purpose. I suggest <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>.

- Open *Edit* > *User Preferences* > *Input*
- Search "Set 3D cursor"
- Edit the first entry (under "3D view"), by clicking on the current key binding and by "recording" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> (you can change it later to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Action Mouse</kbd> for compatibility with left-click-select mode)

  [image]
- "*Save User Settings*"

It should work fine. Using <kbd>LMB</kbd> alone will still work in modes other than *Draw*, and the *Lasso select* should still work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> if you do click-and-drag instead of click-and-release.

Comment: I changed the mouse settings in Blender 2.80 so be like 2.79, so that RMB selects, and LMB moves the 3d cursor, and this works in Draw mode as well. I still hold down LMB to draw a line, but when I click LMB, it moves the 3d cursor. I'm using the most recent Blender 2.80 (6/15/2019).

Answer (score 0):

and if you are using the blender 2.79 setting you can copy the code for the 3d cursor shortcut and create a new shortcut so both of them will work

PS. the code for the 3d cursor shortcut is view3d.cursor3d

[image]