# Grease Pencil - Can't move 3d cursor with pen tablet, can't specify new hotkey

Tags: interface, customization, grease-pencil, 3d-cursor, keymap

I am using Blender 2.9 & 3.0 with right-click select mouse button preference and a drawing tablet without pen buttons.
By default, the 3d cursor moves with <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> click.

By default in Grease Pencil Draw mode, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> click sets the 3d cursor.

With my left-mouse preference, it changes to <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> /  <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Pen-Click</kbd>, which draws instead.

This means I have to switch to another mode (edit/object/etc) + switch from pen back to mouse and back every time I move the 3d cursor

I tried changing the hotkey with a combo that doesn't get overridden by existing hotkeys (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>Pen</kbd>), however, this only worked when the pen-specific shortcut was set to the universal *Set 3d Cursor*, overriding the default left-mouse in every other mode.

I tried setting the pen-specific hotkey for *Set 3d cursor* in *3d View Tool: Sculpt Gpencil, Tweak* and *3d View Tool: Edit Gpencil, Tweak*, but that had no apparent effect on the default 3d cursor placement in GPencil draw mode.

[This thread recommended adding a duplicate hotkey](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120614/moving-the-3d-cursor-while-in-blender-2-8s-grease-pencil-draw-mode) to work simultaneously with the the default universal *Set 3D cursor*, but I can't find how to do this, and am not sure if it still works in later versions.

Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: could you share the file , please?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xk8bkzqeltmkt9t/Grease%20Pencil%20Stack.blend?dl=0 Here's a quick thing I made, though the UI problem persists in new projects too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hotkey in 3D View section, 3D View Generic. It could be a keyboard key as well as it might interfere less with other mouse functions.

Just go to the preferences(F4 > P), Keymap Tab, and navigate to 3D View, 3D View Generic and click Add New, then enter `view3d.cursor3d` and choose a hotkey:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly Thank you SO much!!! I spent the entire day trying to get this to work, and was thinking I had to relearn the workflow with left mouse entirely ahhh THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: If the answer was helpful, consider up-voting it.

Comment: I'm too new for that feature, but I will as soon as I am able!